# How to access subclass method if given Class.class and object reference?

Tags: java, casting, subclass

Given the code below:

Parent class:

```
public class Animal {
  //...
}
```

Subclasses:

```
public class Cat extends Animal {
    public void method2(){
        System.out.println("cat method2");
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal{
    public void method2(){
        System.out.println("dog method2");
    }
}
```

Enum:

```
public enum Values {
    VALUE1("v1", Cat.class),
    VALUE2("v2", Dog.class);

    private String val;
    private Class<?> clazz;

    Values(String val, Class<?> clazz){
        this.val = val;
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public String getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public Class<?> getClazz() {
        return clazz;
    }

}
```

Main class :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal a = new Cat();
        method("VALUE1", a);
    }

    public static void method(String val, Animal a){
        Values value = Values.valueOf(val);

        value.getClazz().cast(a).method2();// this doesn't work. how to access method2?
    }
}
```

The code above won't work. How can I access method2 using Class.class reference? How can I cast The generic `Animal` class into a subclass given the parameters? If Class.class is not possible, what are the alternatives?

Comment: You'd need reflection to do that. The actual question is: why is `method2()` not defined in the parent-class? This would simplify things considerably.

Comment: Sounds like possible [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Chaosfire, basically, based on the given code, I want to access method2 using Cat.class given the constraints if it is even possible.

Comment: How do you know that `method2()` is accessible on the given instance `Animal` if it's not declared by the parent? It `Animal` has this method - simply use it and benefit from the Polymorphism. As an alternative, you can introduce an interface declaring the `method2()`.

Comment: If it's some kind of self-imposed challenge, then you need to elaborate what the idea behind it.

Comment: @atan Is there a reason you don't declare the method in `Animal` as Turing suggested?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko yes, it is indeed some kinda self-imposed challenge in an attempt to understand some Java concepts better. The given code is just a simplification of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @atan *"given code is just a simplification of what I'm trying to do"* - Ok, how about a more exact giving a more exact description of what you were trying to do? It would make the question more valuable for the readers and you might get a few more helpful suggestions.

Comment: Lets split `value.getClazz().cast(a).method2()` into `Class<?> clazz = value.getClazz(); clazz.cast(a).method2();`. If we had for instance `Class<Foo> cs;` the `cs.cast(a);` would be similar to `(Foo)a`. But with `Class<?> clazz` the `cast` is like trying to write `(?)a`. Since compiler doesn't know what type `?` is, the only safe one which it can use as result of `cast` is `Object`. So the `clazz.cast(a).method2()` is same as `Object cast = clazz.cast(a); cast.method2();`. But since `Object` doesn't have `method2` compiler gives you error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option, and best option IMO, is to make `Animal` abstract and add an `abstract method2()` to `Animal`. Then you can implement it in `Cat` and `Dog` and invoke it without using Reflection. Second option, use reflection.

```
public static void method(String val, Animal a) {
    Values value = Values.valueOf(val);
    try {
        Method m = value.getClazz().getMethod("method2", null);
        m.invoke(a, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**or** without `Values`, because that isn't doing much for you like

```
public static void method(Animal a) {
    try {
        Method m = a.getClass().getMethod("method2", null);
        m.invoke(a, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Both methods output

```
cat method2
```

Comment: Well, I didn't know that the reference to the subclass is not really necessary. I only added the enum Values to find a possible solution. It turns out, I'm only over-complicating things. Thanks!